# Use Xpath to query HTML in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xpath

I am struggling to query text and value of HTML `<select><option>` for 2 days, But no luck so far.

I have a html document, the content of a select like below,

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlAreas" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAreas">
    <option value="01">Area1</option>
    <option value="02">Area2</option>
    <option value="03">Area3</option>
    <option value="04">Area4</option>
</select>
```

I am using xPath expression to retrieve:

```
//select[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAreas\"]/option/text()
```

the inner text of option, like Area1, 2, 3, 4...

I am using xPath expression to retrieve

```
//select[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAreas\"]/option/@value
```

the value of option, 01, 02, 03, 04...

Actually,I want both of the inner text and value to be extracted, and combined by a delimiter, such as "#". The output I would like to be,

```
Area1#01,
Area2#02
Area3#03
Area4#04....
```

I tried to use the method `concat()`,

```
//select[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAreas\"]/option/[concat(/text(),\"#\",/@value)]
```

but it seems that only the first option - Area1 is returned, and there is not any delimiter at all.

I appreciate if anybody figures out a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could there be a better solution that retrievs both the text and value one time via an XPath expression?

No, this cannot be done with a single XPath 1.0 expression. The reason why a solution using `concat()` :

```
concat(//select[@id = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAreas']/option/text(),"#",//select[@id = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAreas']/option/@value)
```

only returns the first result:

```
Area1#01
```

is that functions in XPath 1.0 that expect a single node as argument, when handed a sequence of nodes, only process the first one and ignore all the rest. Also, in XPath 1.0, functions cannot really be *steps* in path expressions.

In XPath 2.0 you could have

```
//select[@id = 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAreas']/option/concat(.,'#',@value)
```

and `concat()` would be applied to each `option` element in turn.

---

To sum up, this cannot be done with pure XPath 1.0. Retrieve all the `option` element nodes with an XPath expression and process them further *outside* of XPath, in the higher-level language you embed XPath in - as exemplified by myte.

Answer (score 1):

you could use an xml/html parser such tfhpple to parse your html

https://github.com/topfunky/hpple

```
#import "TFHpple.h"

NSString * html = @"<select name=\"ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlAreas\" id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAreas\"><option value=\"01\">Area1</option><option value=\"02\">Area2</option><option value=\"03\">Area3</option><option value=\"04\">Area4</option></select>";

NSData* data = [html dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

TFHpple *parser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:data];
NSString *optionPath = @"//select[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAreas\"]/option";
NSArray *optionNodes = [parser searchWithXPathQuery:optionPath];

for (TFHppleElement *element in optionNodes) {

    NSDictionary * attributes = [element attributes];

    if ([attributes objectForKey:@"value"]){

        NSString * str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@#%@",element.text, [attributes objectForKey:@"value"]];

        NSLog(@"%@", str);

    }

}
```

output is

Area1#01

Area2#02

Area3#03

Area4#04

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yep, I already used TFHpple. Also now I have a alternative solution is very similar with yours - iterate the attributes, then combine the element.text, and value. I guess this is not the best solution. Could there be a better solution that retrievs both the text and value one time via an XPath expression? like @"//select[@id=\"ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ddlAreas\"]/option[concat(/text(), @value)]"?